# Black box over MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, mkmapview

I have an `MKMapView` and another `UIView` subclass that is overlaid on top of the map. The custom view is transparent (I use it to overlay an inner shadow around the edge of the map). Now when I drop a pin on the map view a small black square shows up over the pin. It seems to disappear and change size randomly too. I can't take a screenshot of it because for some reason it doesn't appear in screenshots. I know it's related to the custom view that's overlaid on the map because when I remove it everything works fine.

Any ideas?

EDIT: As requested here's the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

and the code for the shadow overlay view:

```
self.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8f alpha:0.6f].CGColor;
self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
```

I place the shadow overlay view in IB and that code is in the drawRect method of the view subclass.

Comment: If you can't get a screenshot from the usual way, either grab one by running the iOS simulator and then taking one... or the old-fashioned way with another camera-capable device.

Comment: Can you show the code that creates and adds the "shadow overlay" view?

Comment: Try setting masksToBounds and clipsToBounds to NO.

Comment: That takes care of the black box, but it also causes the shadow to appear outside of the border. I only want it on the inside.

Comment: Put your non-clipped shadow view inside another view with clipping on, this will clip the shadow on the outside of the box.

Comment: Thanks! That worked beautifully. If you post this as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @SimonLee oops, forgot to use '@' Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your non-clipped shadow view inside another view with clipping on, this will clip the shadow on the outside of the box.